# Release an orphaned Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Running on pyspark on Spark v2.0.0, I can create an orphaned object like so:

```
result = myDataFrame.filter('col1="value"').cache().to_Pandas()
```

This will return a Pandas dataframe, and cache an unnamed RDD in Spark. I can clear the orphan with `sqlContext.clearCache()` but that will remove all persisted RDDs. Is there any way to:

a) Find out from my current session which objects are cached (without going to the UI), and

b) unpersist an RDD without a rdd/dataframe object to use?

Comment: Caching like this doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I realise that it is a daft thing to do - and in practice I wouldn't do it - but it came up during an attempt to locate a Spark memory leak. I figured there should be _some_ way to find the orphans and kill them without having to purge everything...

Comment: OK, now it makes more sense :)